# Coin Cell Powered Bluetooth "water on floor" sensor(rope type)

Tags: bluetooth, sensor

disclaimer, I am quite new to development of solutions around the Raspberry PI, so please forgive If I'm slow at grasping something but, I'm trying to put together a package to implement across several IT sites and I'd like to leverage a RPi at each site and connect sensors to monitor the environment around server racks.  Temp/Humidity seemed to be easy to put in place, but I'm wondering if anyone has already written a recipe for a Coin Cell Powered Bluetooth "water on floor" sensor?
Here is a commercially available example:
https://www.monnit.com/Products/Wireless-Sensors/Coin-Cell/Wireless-Water-Rope-Sensors
I've seen a couple similar projects, such as http://projects.privateeyepi.com/home/home-alarm-system-project/wireless-projects/flood-water-presence-sensor
but even that one is not Bluetooth. 
I've found lots of solutions that connect to proprietary controllers, or are Wi-Fi(for sending emails, for example), but I really like the idea of being able to have one that is not dependent on WiFi being available and can connect to a RPi, so that battery status can be monitored as well.
Any thoughts, ideas, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Raspberry Pi wont run of a coin cell. You should have searched google on that already before asking here. Those products you mentioned need a dedicated gateway, so the coin sensor just sends a simple single to it. The coin sensor is probably a very simple, low power, super efficient design based on "switch" on when water causes a short across the wire. So technically the coin device is never on, until the liquid causes it to turn on. So how does a Raspberry Pi fit into this? PS - You should also read the FAQ of this site because your question consists of several questions and is objective.

Comment: thanks for the quick feedback, ppumkin.  For clarification, I'm not seeking how to run a Pi off of a coin cell battery...was just pinging the community to see if anyone was aware of an existing recipe or project already done to make the leak sensor (with coin cell pwrd Bluetooth) for use with a Pi.   I will admit I haven't read the FAQ.  That said, I did see numerous posts here regarding sensors for Pi which I why I thought this would be an OK place to post my question.

Comment: OK no problem . Just a tip, it is more likely your question will stay open longer if you format it a bit nicer. But it depends once the mods make their round and unleash the wrath of "close this question because its to broad" - which it is. I personally never even knew something like that existed. You may have to find each part and try and get it working your self. When you get stuck with a specific thing it is better to ask more specific question here then, or electronics exchange if its electronics related.